# Normalising a wave function in parts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

If we have the wave function $\psi_{100}(r,\theta,\phi)=R_{10}(r)Y_{00}(\theta,\phi)$ when we are normalising it we do the following:
$$1=\int| \psi_{100}(r,\theta,\phi)|^2sin(\theta)  r^2drd\theta d\phi$$ but can we also normalise the individual parts separately i.e. 
$$1=\int r^2|R_{10}(r)|^2 dr $$ and $$1=\int |Y_{00}(\theta,\phi)|^2 sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi  $$ I ask this as this is what my textbook is doing and knowing integration it seems wrong! Please if this is right can you explain it, thanks.

Comment: This is standard [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) techniques. You could choose $\lambda=\int r^2|R|^2\,dr$ and $\lambda^{-1}=\int |Y|^2d\Omega$, but why not take $\lambda=1$ and make it simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not wrong, all three normalization conditions are natural and they don't contradict each other because, in fact, the first equation is nothing else than the product of the following two equations! Just substitute your formula for $\psi$, $\psi = R Y$, to the first equation.

The only mistake you have to fix to show that the first equation becomes the product of the other two is to replace the wrong (and really nonsensical, one can't integrate over same $r$ "twice" in one integral) $drdr$ in the first equation by the correct $r^2 dr$.

The first integral splits to the product because some factors in the integrand only depend on the radial coordinate $r$ so they can be taken out of the integral and integrated over $r$ separately while the remaining factors only depend on the angles $\theta,\phi$. As Kyle said, the general technique is called the "separation of variables".

Comment: Are we saying that $\int g(x)h(y)dxdy=\int \int g(x)h(y)dxdy=\int g(x)dx \int h(y)dy$ also (i know this is slightly off topic but) does $d^3r=drdrdr$ or something different? thanks

Comment: Dear Joseph, yes, the identity for $\int g(x)h(y) dx dy$ is exactly the identity used here, with $x$ replaced by the radial $r$ and $y$ replaced by the two-dimensional integral over the angles. The $d^3r$ means $dx\,dy\,dz=dV$, it's an infinitesimal volume in a volume integral. A volume integral is the same thing as an integral over three variables, like $x,y,z$ or $r,\theta,\phi$, so the integral contains $dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$ as well as some extra Jacobian (measure) factor $r^2\sin\theta$, in this case. You can't write $dx\,dy\,dz$ as $dr\,dr\,dr$ because you need to integrate over 3 axes.